# Get ASCII from int variable

Tags: c#, .net

Here is what I've tried

```
            int two = 2;
            int asciiX = (int) 'x';
            int asciiTwo = (int) two;
            Console.WriteLine("The ascii value of 2 is " + asciiTwo);
            Console.WriteLine("The ascii value of x is " + asciiX););
```

I expected the output to be 50 as the ascii value of 2 is 50  (which is the ASCII code of '2')

But I got this result :

```
The ascii value of 2 is 2
The ascii value of x is 120 (it's working for x)
```

I know that if I put `int asciiTwo = '2';` it will works, but it's not directly processing from the variable how can I do, to get the ascii code of a number which is in a int variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`two` is an `int` with value `2`. You are casting an `int` to an `int`. That does not change anything.

You can get the ASCII value using two ways at least:

```
(int)(two.ToString())[0] //the first char of the string representation of two
(int)(two + '0') //numbers start at '0' in the ASCII table
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the `two` variable as `int`. The `int` of an `int` is the `int` itself.

What you want is to declare it as `char` or `string`, too.

```
char two = '2';
int asciiTwo = (int) two;
```